# Is "inline" needed with member function templates

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a member function template in a non-template class and want to define it outside the class - do I have to use "inline"?

Example:

```
class A
{
    template <class D>
    void someMethod(D param);
}

template <class D>
/* inline needed here? */ void A::someMethod(D param)
{
}
```

Section 3.2.5 of the standard says function templates do not fall under the One Definition Rule. Is a member function template a function template in this regard?

Edit: The linker does not complain without inline - but still - is it valid C++03?

Edit:

What I have learned so far: gcc (and assumingly other compilers, too) export implicit template instantiations as *weak symbols*, meaning no conflict will occur during link time if they are instantiated in multiple translation units. As *weak symbols* are not part of the standard - does the standard somehow implicitly require template instantiations to behave this way and can I expect the same behaviour with other standard conforming compiler/linker combinations?

As *inline* is basically ignored for optimization but allows for multiple definitions of functions in different translation units this implicitly translates to exporting these functions as *weak symbols*. Does this mean declaring a template as *inline* is redundant?

Comment: yes, compiler does not complain. However not everything that satisfies the compiler is valid C++ ;) We just had a discussion here and nobody was quite sure.

Comment: The compiler can't complain since it sees only one Translation Unit at a time, and an ODR violation occurs when something is defined in two Translation Units.

Comment: Does `inline` have any syntactical meaning? I always thought it was just an optimization suggestion for the compiler.

Comment: @Philipp - inline has semantic meaning; it tells the compiler that multiple definitions of the same inline function in different translation units is not a violation of the one-definition-rule. It also imposes its own rule, that all definitions must be identical.

Comment: Just check your C++ book on the ODR (one definition rule) and everything should get clearer.

Comment: @MSalters: I meant the gcc/ld combination.

Comment: @HannoStock: Well, `ld` has similar problems. It sees multiple TU's, but only the external symbols. And inlined symbols need not be external (per the standard) since every TU has its own identical copy, per the ODR. So gcc can't and ld can't, and the combination therefore can't either.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not member function templates are function templates, they are certainly not objects or non-inline functions, so the One Definition Rule does not apply.

But they actually are function templates, and do count as such for other applications of the Standard that are not specific to non-member function templates.

Answer (score 0):

`inline` as a keyword is there to suggest to the compiler that function marked as such are good candidates for the optimization having the same name, and as a help to implement such optimization it mandates that the function is to be defined -- **in the same way** -- in each CU where it is used (it far easier for a compiler to do the optimization if it see the code, even if linkers are able to do the same optimization, it was far less common 20 years ago).

You may want to give this hint for function templates and thus mark a function template definition inline. If you don't want to give that hint, inline is not needed.

(There was a time now passed when only functions marked inline were considered for the optimization, but the keyword hasn't met yet the fate of `register`, i.e. being generally ignored by compilers excepted for its formal meaning of preventing to take the address of a variable).

Comment: Well... `inline` is more about avoiding ODR violations than hinting the compiler. At one point in time it was regarded as a good hint by compilers then they decided that people did not really knew and compilers started ignoring it as a performance hint. Compilers then produced their own non-standard performance hints that would force inlining. Then they decided that people did not really know so even those non-standard forms are more often than not ignored by compilers...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, My understanding is that it is really considered as an hint.  Not as a mandate, but not completely ignored either yet (like `register` is), just an additional parameter in the more or less complex function evaluating the interest of applying the optimization, and probably a parameter of decreasing importance with time (process driven not only by the amelioration of the inlining algorithms, but also of the number of "header only" libraries which (ab?)uses inline in order to meet that goal, decreasing its value as a driver for the optimization).

Comment: @AProgrammer Your understanding is partially wrong. Yes, as far as the actual inlining goes an implementation is free to ignore it. But additionally, declaring a function inline effectively **requires** the implementation to "fold" all definitions (which must be "exactly the same" -- draft n4659, 10.1.6/6) into one. This prevents duplicate symbol errors at the link stage which would otherwise occur. This is pretty clear fromt he use case to have the inline definition in a header which is potentially included in many places, relieving the linker from inlining duties.